# Windows 7 reinstallation and Visual Studio Express 2010/Community 2013 registration key

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I have to reinstall my Windows 7. Do I have to obtain a new registration key for my Visual Studio Express 2010/Community 2013 or I can use my old key from previous installation?

Best Regards,
Jacek

Answer (score 0):

I do know that express is a free version. If you are talking about registration keys as in free to premium, then you do not have to worry as all your codes save via cloud and you don't have to get a new one.